# Custom Annotation View Callout Not Showing

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have made a custom annotation and custom annotation views but for some reason the callouts are not showing.

```
class MyAnnotation: NSObject,MKAnnotation {

    var coordinate :CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title :String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(coordinate :CLLocationCoordinate2D, title :String?, subtitle :String?) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
    }

}
```

**Annotation View**

```
class MyAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        self.canShowCallout = true

        let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")

        let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        logo?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        let logoImageView = UIImageView(image: resizedImage)
        logoImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        self.addSubview(logoImageView)
    }
```

**Populating Annotations**

```
private func populateAnnotations() {

        for location in self.locations {

            let annotation = MyAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude), title: location.name, subtitle: "nothing")

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }





 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let annotationView = MyAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "AnnotationView")

        return annotationView

    }
```

When I click on the custom annotation it does not show a callout.

Comment: It's a little odd that you set `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` on the `logoImageView`.  If you remove that, does anything change?

Comment: Removing it does not make a difference!

Comment: The only other options are that your annotation's `title` property is `nil` or that you've set the `enabled` property of the annotation view to `false`.  You may want to verify that isn't the case with the debugger or print statements in `mapView(_:viewForAnnotation:)`

Comment: Just checked: title is not nil and I have not set enabled to false.